# Cannot access to dockerized mssql server

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

I'm trying to dockerize two .net core 3.1 service (my-api and my-db).
my-db service is using mssql database and I'm using scripts below to create actual db insi de container as soon as it get up

```
docker-compose up --build
```

services are up and running but when I use api service to access db I'm getting
An error occurred using the connection to database 'mydatabase' on server 'my-db'.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.0' 
services:
  my-db:
    build: ./Data/Docker
  my-api:
    ports: 
      - "8080:5000"         
    depends_on: 
      - my-db
   ... ommited for clarity
```

**Data/Docker**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU17-ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
COPY . /usr/src/app    
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh    
ENV SA_PASSWORD pass
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_PID Express    
EXPOSE 1433    
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
/usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

**run-initialization.sh**

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P pass -d master -i create-database.sql
```

**create-database.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE [mydatabase] 
GO
USE [mydatabase]
GO
```

Comment: The SQL server Service takes some time starting up, so I would suggest adding a sleep of 10 seconds before you try to connect to the database in `run-initialization.sh`

Comment: make sense, tried with /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd sleep 10 -S localhost -U sa -P pass -d master -i create-database.sql
but I'm having same issue. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `entrypoint.sh` like this

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & sleep 10 & /usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh
```

- `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` starts the SQL server
- `sleep 10` waits for 10 seconds
- `/usr/src/app/run-initialization.sh` executes run-initialization.sh, which connects to the SQL Server and creates a database.

Answer (score -1):

What do you have in connection string?

It need to match  dbserver name with your db name in compose as far as i remember so in your case:
my-db